# Why is ion-item click not working in ionic4 for ios?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

`ion-item` clickable event not working in ios but its working fine in android. Please help me, I am wasting my time in & I have searched lot of in google but find any sutaible answer.

```
  <ion-content >
   <div>       
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list  lines="full" >
      <ion-item class="bg-class" *ngFor="let project of filterData" (click)="onProjectClick(project.npProjCode);">
       <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright-circle" style="width: 14px;margin-right: 10px;color: #129bcc;"></ion-icon>
       <ion-label>{{project.npProjDescn}}</ion-label> 
       <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" slot="end" style="color: lightgray;"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you please try ng-container like this http://keepnote.cc/share/culex-6143

Comment: Share me your .ts code of `onProjectClick`

Comment: async onProjectClick(projectCode) { console.log("ProjectCode:= "+projectCode)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got solution, Its work in ios & android

```
<ion-item button class="bg-class" *ngFor="let project of filterData" (click)="onProjectClick(project.npProjCode);">
```

-

```
ion-item[button] {
      pointer-events: initial !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

last time I have this problem I fix it like this , hop it work for you

```
@ViewChild('searchbar', { static: true }) searchbar: IonSearchbar;

ngOnInit() {

this.sub = this.searchbar.ionInput
      .subscribe(q => this.getItems(q))
}
```

*template*

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar ></ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: Search is working fine, problem is that ion-item click not work in ios.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem, but after login. It was called at background. On Android it worked normally, however, on iOS it did not work at all.

Try to debug if Its not the same problem in .ts